# ¿Por qué sale el error -- >TypeError: d.getDay is not a function en un Mat - datepicker?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

Tengo un calendario y le puse como filtro una funcion para que deshabilite los dias del fin de semana (sabados y domingos) y que no se puedan escoger del calendario , pero al desplegar el calendario sale el error en la consola y no te deja escoger

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: d.getDay is not a function
>
> ```
> at DiaInhabComponent.disabledWeekend [as dateFilter]
> ```

html

```
               <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Fecha Inhábil</mat-label>
                            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="fechaInhabil"
                            [matDatepickerFilter]="disabledWeekend"/>
                            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="nuevoDiaInhabilForm.controls.fechaInhabil.hasError('required')">Este campo es obligatorio</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```
disabledWeekend = (d: Date): boolean => {
    const day = d.getDay();
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  }
```

por qué sale ese error y cómo lo puedo soluionar?
o como más podria validar que se deshabiliten esos dias del calendario?

Comment: Usas la implementacion de `MatNativeDateModule`?

Comment: si, la tengo importada en mi app.module, por?

Comment: podrias poner en consola el valor de `d`? Para confirmar que estas recibiendo una fecha del tipo `Date`.

Comment: @eventHandler  ya meti un console.log para ver el valor de d, pero esque ni escoger la fecha me deja, cuando despliego el calendario sale el error y no lo muestra, adjunto imagen

Comment: tendra que ver que tambien tengo importado este modulo   MatMomentDateModule y esto en mi provider:    providers: [
    {provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue:  { useUtc: false } },
  ]